# Only local administrators can connect remotely

Tags: sql-server-express, logins, kerberos, spn

I'm facing a problem that when I try to connect to the SQL Express instance from client to server. The Server logs an error:

> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while
>   establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has
>   been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error
>   code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt failed
>   [CLIENT: 192.168.245.50]

The account I log on with is sysadmin and have all the possible permissions on the database its trying to connect to but still it fails. But if I add the user that is trying to connect to the local administrators group it works. This is not a good solution, I don't want all users to be local administrators on the server. Why is it that the user needs to be local admin?

And I think the SPN is correctly set.

[image]

Its all in same domain and using domain accounts. 
Windows Autentication is used for login.
Shouldnt be problem with the connectivity to the DC. 
Named instances name is used (it works if the domain user is local admin).

Log from SQL error log:

> 03/09/2015 15:22:47,Logon,Unknown,Login failed. The login is from an
>   untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
>   [CLIENT: 192.168.245.50] 03/09/2015 15:22:47,Logon,Unknown,Error:
>   18452 Severity: 14 State: 1. 03/09/2015
>   15:22:47,Logon,Unknown,SSPI handshake failed with error code
>   0x8009030c state 14 while establishing a connection with
>   integrated security; the connection has been closed. Reason:
>   AcceptSecurityContext failed. The Windows error code indicates the
>   cause of failure. The logon attempt failed   [CLIENT: 192.168.245.50]
>   03/09/2015 15:22:47,Logon,Unknown,Error: 17806 Severity: 20
>   State: 14.

Log from the client trying to connect:

> LSRetailPosis.POS.Program: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and
>   cannot be used with Windows authentication.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   LSRetailPosis.Settings.Database.CheckDatabaseExistence()    at
>   LSRetailPosis.Settings.Database.CheckDatabaseSettings()    at
>   LSRetailPosis.Settings.ApplicationSettings.InitializeSettings(String[]
>   args)    at LSRetailPosis.POS.Program.InitializeAndLoadPOS(String[]
>   args, Boolean owned, SplashScreenForm splashScreenForm)    at
>   LSRetailPosis.POS.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   ClientConnectionId:d57c7fd9-4a47-41b7-af07-ed93627d2930.

Comment: Is it a windows domain account, a local windows account, or a sql auth account? Are you both on the same domain? Any issues with connectivity to the domain controller? Are you specifying the instance name when connecting? Can you provide the error messages from the SQL Server error log, which may contain a little more detail? (The state in SQL Server's error log will be something other than 14, which I believe in the error message your client is showing is actually the severity.)

Comment: Updated the question with answers.

Comment: So here is a clue: `The login is from an untrusted domain`... have you considered using SQL auth remotely if you can't set up domain trusts / Kerberos etc. between the two machines?

Comment: It's Dyanmics AX POS client, I cant use SQL auth. It´s the same domain. If i login with my own account that is local admin on the SQL server it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem like SQL Server thinks the account is coming from the same domain.

Comment: @Aaron, it works if i add the account to local administrators.

Comment: Right, so it sounds like SQL Server is expecting a role/login from the local machine and *not* from the domain. You are probably succeeding in that case because the domain that is authenticated is the local workstation, not the proper domain. Have you tried creating a local group that is *not* the administrators group, adding the windows domain account to that group, and granting that group access in SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, i've added the domain account to the local group POSUsers that has correct permission in SQL Server. Didnt work.

Comment: I also tried adding the user directly to the SQL logins with sysadmin and all other permissions and i got same error.

Comment: instead of local admin, have you tried adding the account to the remote users? You can Start-> RClick Computer -> Properties -> Remote Settings -> Make sure "Allow connections ..." is selected and click Select Users -> Add the user

Comment: @user16484 didnt make any diffrent. Im not trying to connect with RDP. Its a client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem.

I added the domain user to: Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Access this computer from the Network

[image]